# Find IdentityServer4 errors in Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have the following setup:

- ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, deployed to an Azure App Service
- Uses IDS4 via the `IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity` package, version 3.1.0
- In `Program.cs` it calls `.UseApplicationInsights()` from `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` version 2.5.1
- The `Default` `LogLevel` is set to `Warning`
- My `Error.cshtml` shows `Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier`

This properly logs several things from the app service, but I cannot find *any* errors reported by IDS4 that were on the OpenID/OAuth2 protocol level (e.g. invalid scopes requested and such). For example, I can find stuff like this:

```
requests
| where cloud_RoleName == 'my-identity-server-4-role'
| order by timestamp desc
| where url contains 'errorId'
| limit 100
```

And this makes sense because I have some (other) issue with logins, where an implicit flow silent refresh fails and redirects to a problem url a la `https://my-identity-domain.example.org/home/error?errorId=some-long-string-here`. That page shows me an error page that explains I could turn on DeveloperExceptionPage features on my machine, or I could use:

> Request ID: |123aaac2c1cccf4eb3333411aaa183da7e.bba43cca1_

Now I try to find the `requests` entryin AppInsights by

- `| where id contains "123aaac2c"` or
- `| where operation_Id contains "123aaac2c"` or
- `| where operation_ParentId contains "123aaac2c"` or
- `| where session_Id contains "123aaac2c"` or
- `| where itemId contains "123aaac2c"`
- `| where problemId contains "123aaac2c"`

And similar for `exceptions` where any of the id fields contains part of my id. But I can't seem to find the results.

What am I doing wrong? Am I still looking in the wrong places? Or should I increase log levels somehow? Or do I need to add code somewhere to configure IdentityServer4 to log this stuff?

---

Note: if I run my application locally from the console, I do see output stream by for errors. For example, I've added `_logger.LogError("test error")` inside startup, and configured my SPA to use my local IDS but with improper scope, and I see this output:

```
fail: MyApp.Identity.Startup[0]
      test error
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\git\my-app\MyApp.Identity
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ScopeValidator[0]
      Invalid scope: triggererroridwithinvalidscope
fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Request validation failed
```

The first error was just to check how normal errors are logged, and the second error was to simulate my actual issue (that triggers an `errorId` page as mentioned earlier in my question).

In short, I do see things logged on the console via ASP.NET Core logging, but I can not find them in AppInsights.

---

Note: I further researched how IdentityServer4 does its logging, and [as documented](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/logging.html) it logs using the ASP.NET Core default logging system, by injecting e.g. an `ILogger<T>` from Microsoft's Abstractions, and then using a few helper methods to call ([for example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/eb6221c6b4a24e1192e9fd157b9d502527e1c360/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/TokenRequestValidator.cs#L761-L764)):

```
var details = new TokenRequestValidationLog(_validatedRequest);
// abbreviated snippet
_logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "Some message" + ", details: {@details}", details);
```

Maybe this doesn't show up in AppInsights because there is no good place for it? It's not a Trace, it's not a Request, and it has no real Exception either?

Comment: Few months later, had a fresh look today at our production setup. Still cannot find these errors in AppInsights, nor any way to get it to work. 

Answer (score 3):

If you need to find correlated log entries to an error in Application Insights, you can  search for the Request ID that is shown on the IdentityServer error page. The Request ID comes from the `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.Id` property and should be automatically attached to the log event. You can query it like this:

```
traces
| where customDimensions["RequestId"] == "80006a82-0000-e800-b63f-84710c7967bb"
| order by timestamp desc
| limit 50
```

Regarding the identity server events not showing up at all in Insights, could you try to add this to your `Startup` class?

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
})
```

Also note that it can take some time until the log events actually show up in the Application Insights log viewer. To exclude this as a problem source, I'd wait a few minutes before running your query.

Comment: Thx for taking the time to respond! I tried your suggestions, to no avail, alas. I searched in both `requests` and `exceptions` as you did not mention which one I should check. - PS. I notice you suggest to expect a GUID, but the format of the `Request ID` IDS gives me is `\|[0-9a-z]+\.[0-9a-z]+_` so e.g. `|ae33f334......a32af_`. - I also did wait a few mins, and did try to account for possible sampling issues...

Comment: The identity server events can be found in `traces`. Have you already looked there?

Comment: I have, just now, but couldn't find any IDS traces yet. Thx for the suggestion though, I will continue [crafting a minimal repro](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-identityserver4-with-appinsights) and see if your help will lead me to the final culprit in my production application.

Comment: We are leaving the Q&A scope here, but nevertheless I tested the code inside the repository you linked and it works fine for me. I simply replaced the instrumentation key in the `appsettings.json` with the one for my own Insights instance. After provoking an error I was able to see the trace errors generated by IdentityServer along with the Request ID attached. I'd suggest to double check that your instrumentation key is correctly loaded and that there are no other configuration issues with your Insights instance.